# R with CGI Web Interface - Most flexible option

Tags: r, rapache

I have been exploring some options for implementing an R Web interface where users will have the option of selecting certain criteria, for eg., date ranges, plot type, etc. The issue is that a number of the R web interfaces that are listed in CRAN seem to have been last updated 5-6 yrs back ... and the most recent / up-to-date implementation seems to be RApache. From the site of Jeffrey Oons, a number of good examples of how to use RApache with JSON was available that looked quite impressive. However, as of this time, it seems that RApache only runs on Debian / Ubuntu / Mac.

I wanted to ask if anyone is aware of other R web-based implementation that can produce nice looking webpages (eg., display a dataframe within a scrollable widget, display ggplot2 objects, etc).

Also - does anyone have RApache running on Redhat / Solaris ?

Answer (score 0):

There is [an entire section in the R FAQ devoted on web interfaces](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces) to R.

Also consider the relatively new [Rook](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rook) package which utilizes the web server embedded in R itself since release 2.13.0 (which R uses for its help system).